# Creating table in Snowflake from external stage when there are several files in blob

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Im trying to create an external table in Snowflake by using an external stage in Azure blob storage. Query runs witout errors but since there are several files in the external stage I can not successfully create a table with data from a correct file which I want to load in. Even though I have been trying to specify the file name by writing different path I still dont get the table with the right data.
Does anyone know how to specify a file among many files in an external stage?
I would also like to update the table in Snowflake evey time the file has been updated in Azure blob storage. How would you do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An External table points to a location and stores file-level metadata. One cannot create a table for a specific file but you can use the where clause to specify the medata$filename and narrow down the results. The files in the location can be updated manually using an Alter refresh statement or setting up auto-refresh. details can be found here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-external-azure.html